# Definir el valor de una variable al mencionar un canal en discord.py (un bot)

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

estoy creando un bot en discord, y a la vez aprendiendo programación, estoy usando una librería de Python, he aprendido bastante, pero me estanqué en esto, necesito que al escribir un comando por ejemplo `!canal` y mencionar un canal, o sea `!canal @asd`, la variable `canalseleccionado` pase a tomar la ID del canal mencionado, esto es lo que intenté, pero no funciona.

```
canalseleccionado = "No configurado"

@bot.command(aliases=["Comando para seleccionar el canal"])
async def canal(ctx, canalseleccionado = TextChannel.mention):
await ctx.send(canalseleccionado)
```

Comment: ahi tu parametro `canalseleccionado` contiene el mensaje que se ha enviado, eso creo, solo seria cuestion de obtener el canal con `TextChannel.mention`

Answer (score 0):

Esto te deberia funcionar (El codigo no esta testeado, si aparece algun error responde y tratare de solucionarlo)

```
canalseleccionado = "No configurado"

@bot.command(aliases=["Comando para seleccionar el canal"])
async def canal(ctx, arg):
    # Cuando se menciona un canal, el formato es el siguiente: <#ID>
    # Reemplazando "<#" y ">" hacemos que solo nos quede la ID en el string

    arg = arg.replace('<#', '')
    arg = arg.replace('>', '')

    try:
        canalseleccionado = bot.get_channel(arg)
    except:
        await ctx.send('ID de canal no valida.')

    await ctx.send(arg)
```